# how to find time taken to load a page

Tags: javascript

How to get the time taken to load the current page.

Is that can we find how much CPU memory utilization for that page to load..?

Comment: Is this something you want to display on the page, or you just want to debug it?

Comment: Including server processing time?  Including image, css and js download times?

While JS might have some control over the latter 3, it has no idea how long it took the server to prepare the results.  It would require the server to record the start time somewhere within the resulting page to get an accurate result.

Why do you need this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a javascript solution, you could sort of profile the time using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ()
{
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        alert("Page took " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms to load");
    }, 0);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox, you can use extensions like Firebug, PageSpeed or YSlow - they will help you to analyze the page load time as well as the bottlenecks in the page load.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).

Right-click on the (bug) icon which has been placed at the bottom right of the Firefox window. Select 'enable all panels'.
Then click on the 'Net' tab, and simply point your browser to the page you want to benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google gave me a script on the first 3 results:

[script](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1908.htm)

[google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=javascript+page+load+time)

I'm thinking you are looking for a javascript solution because you have the javascript tag selected.